# How to check out an existing feature branch with Android repo tool

Tags: repo

A colleague created feature branch `thebranch` using `repo start`.  Now I want to check out this branch and work on it.  I try this:

```
repo init -u git@gitserver:manifest.git -m all.xml
repo sync
repo branches              # Responds "(no branches)"
repo checkout thebranch    # Responds "error: no project has branch thebranch"
```

How do I check out a feature branch that someone else started with `repo start`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to each repository to check out the feature branches, thereby setting up tracking branches:

```
repo forall -p -c git checkout thebranch
```

The `-p` option means "Show project headers before output" and also does pagination, and may be omitted.

Now you can do `repo checkout`:

```
repo checkout thebranch
```

Comment: It is possible to omit the enumeration using `repo forall -p -c git checkout thebranch`

Comment: How serendipitous, Maxim Suslov.  Just a few days after your comment, a colleague asked about this, and I gave him your `-p` suggestion.  It worked, so I edited my answer accordingly.  Thanks!